# Proving $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n < n$ for natural numbers with $n \geq 3$.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Prove with induction on $n$ that \begin{align*} \Bigl(1+ \frac{1}{n}\Bigr)^n < n \end{align*} for natural numbers $n \geq 3$.

**Attempt at proof:** *Basic step.* This can be verified easily.

*Induction step.* Suppose the assertion holds for $n >3$, then we now prove it for $n+1$. We want to prove that \begin{align*} \big( 1+ \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1} < n+1. \end{align*} So we have \begin{align*} \big( 1+ \frac{1}{n+1}\big)^{n+1} &= \big( 1+ \frac{1}{n+1} \big)^n \cdot \big( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \big) \\ & < \big (1 + \frac{1}{n} \big)^n \cdot \big( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \big)  \\ & = n \cdot \big( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \big) \qquad \text{(Induction hypothesis)} \\ &= n \cdot \big( \frac{n+1+1}{n+1} \big) \\ &= \frac{n^2 + 2n}{n+1} \\ &= \frac{(n+1)^2 -1}{(n+1)}
\end{align*}
And now I'm stuck. I don't know how to get $n+1$ on the RHS. Please help!

Comment: @chinny I think the OP wants a solution only using induction.

Comment: @peter cheers for that. Makes it more interesting.

Comment: You were finished on Line 3, since $n\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=n+\frac{n}{n+1}\lt n+1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:
$$
\frac{(n+1)^2-1}{n+1}<\frac{(n+1)^2}{n+1}.
$$

Answer (score 5):

For $n=3$ we have
$(1 + 1/n)^{n} < n$.
If $n \geq 1$ such that
$(1 + 1/n)^{n} < n$,
then
$$
(1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1} < (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n+1} < n(1 + \frac{1}{n}) = n+1,
$$
qed.

Answer (score 2):

First: When using the induction hypothesis it should read as $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\color{red}<\color{black}n\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

Then: $$(n+1)^2-1<(n+1)^2,$$ so we get...can you take it from here?

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing that out. And yes, I found it now!